# Spring generate progressive unique int for entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am working on a REST api in Spring, and I'm required to save
an entity `Document` with a protocol number which consists in:

```
progressiveInt/currentyear
```

Here is the model:

```
@Entity
public class Document {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String protocolNumber;
}
```

I have come up with this solution:

```
public void saveDocument(Document document) {
        Document savedDoc = documentRepository.save(document);

        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String protocolNumber = savedDoc.getId() + "/" + year;
        savedDoc.setProtocolNumber(protocolNumber);

        documentRepository.save(savedDoc);
    }
```

In other words I'm saving the object and updating it using the id the DB created, but I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have code just a bit cleaner you could use `@PostPersist`, so adding method like below to your `Document`:

```
@PostPersist
private void postPersist() {
    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    this.protocolNumber = this.getId() + "/" + year ;       
}
```

You should not need to save / persist instance again after this update. So this if you really need to have `protocolNumber` stored on the database.

But: this `protocolNumber` is also kind a transient value so you might want to consider also adding only field `year` into your `Document`, remove field `protocolNumber` and create a getter like:

```
public String getProtocolNumber() {
    return this.id + "/" + this.year;
}
```

This way you would not need to know the `id` upon persisting.

Comment: Thank you this is great